# React functional component useEffect hook with dependency equal in class component lifecycles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle, react-lifecycle-hooks

I use the useEffect hook inside functional components with a dependency so that dependency changes , useEffect function will re-run like this :

```
const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
 
    console.log("Do something")

} , [show]);
```

I wanted to know what is available in react's class component to do exactly like this ?
Is there any lifecycle method to have this functionality ?

Comment: ˋcomponentDidUpdate` must approach it.  Try to watch the doc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use combination of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidMount(){ //use this method if you want to trigger the side effect first time
   console.log("Do something")
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
  if (this.state.show !== prevState.show) {
    console.log("Do something");
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain, like what exactly that prevProps and prevState is doing here?

Answer (score 0):

To control your component use `shouldComponentUpdate` ([link for the article](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)). It has 2 arguments **nextProps** and **nextState**. You can compare `this.state.field` and `nextState.field` and if they are different make side effect:

```js
class ClickButton extends React.Component {
              
           constructor(props) {
               super(props);
               this.state = {class: "off", label: "press"};
               this.press = this.press.bind(this);
           }
           
           shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
               if(nextState.class !== this.state.class){
                  return true
               }
               return false;
           }
           
           press(){
               var className = (this.state.class==="off")?"on":"off";
               this.setState({class: className});
           }
           render() {
               return <button onClick={this.press} className={this.state.class}>{this.state.label}</button>;
           }
       }
```

If ypu return **true** from this method, it says React that component should update, **false** in other way, Component won't update.

Also you can extends from `PureComponent` ([PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)), it will be automatically follow props and state:

```js
class ClickButton extends React.PureComponent {
              
           constructor(props) {
               super(props);
               this.state = {class: "off", label: "press"};
                  
               this.press = this.press.bind(this);
           }
           
           press(){
               var className = (this.state.class==="off")?"on":"off";
               this.setState({class: className});
           }
           
           render() {
               return <button onClick={this.press} className={this.state.class}>{this.state.label}</button>;
           }
       }
```

But it makes a superficial comparison (by reference). If you have nested fields in you state, and they are changing, PureComponent doesn't rerender Component.

There are other methods like `componentDidUpdate` ([link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)) and `componentDidMount` ([link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)). First, called when component rerender:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
  if (this.state.userID !== prevState.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.state.userID);
  }
}
```

Talking about second one, it will be called when component set in the DOM.

In your case use componentDidUpdate